# Combinatoric Identities

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Ho to prove the following two identities?

I cannot see the trick:

(a) $\binom{-x}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{x+k-1}{k}$

(b) $\binom{k+x}{2k+1}=-\binom{k-x}{2k+1}$

Comment: What is your definition of $\binom{x}{k}$ ? If you write it, you should see the answer.

Comment: I know what you mean, but what about $\binom{-x}{k}$ how should i calculate $(-x)!$?

Comment: This is not the correct definition for $x$ not in $\mathbb N$. $\binom{x}{k}=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}$ (which is **also** the correct and efficient way to compute $\binom nk$ even for $n$ and $k$ integers).

Answer (score 2):

With the hint I provided, the first identity goes this way :
\begin{align}
\binom{-x}{k} &= \frac{(-x)(-x-1)\dots(-x-k+1)}{k!} \\
              &= \frac{(-1)^k(x)(x+1)\dots(x+k-1)}{k!} \\
              &= (-1)^k\binom{x+k-1}{k}
\end{align}
Try to proove the second one by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(2k+1)-(k+x)-1=k-x$, the upper number of $\binom{k-x}{2k+1}$. Thus, you can [negate the upper index](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Negated_Upper_Index_of_Binomial_Coefficient):

$$\binom{k+x}{2k+1}=(-1)^{2k+1}\binom{(2k+1)-(k+x)-1}{2k+1}\;,$$

Therefore:

${k+x \choose 2k + 1}=-{k-x \choose 2k + 1} $

$=(-1)^{2k+1}\binom{(2k+1)-(k+x)-1}{2k+1}\;$

$=(-1)^{2k+1}\binom{2k-(k+x)}{2k+1}$

$=(-1)^{2k+1}\frac{(2k-(k+x)).(2k-(k+x) -1).(2k-(k+x)-2) ... (2k-(k+x)-2k) }{(2k+1)!}$

$=\frac{-1(2k-(k+x)).-1(2k-(k+x) -1).-1(2k-(k+x)-2) ... -1(2k-(k+x)-2k) }{(2k+1)!}$

$=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}.((k+x)-2k).((k+x) -2k +1).((k+x)-2k +2) ... ((k+x)-2k+2k)$

$=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}.(\frac{(k+x)!}{((k+x)-2k-1)!})$

$=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}.(\frac{(k+x)!}{((k+x)-(2k +1))!})$

$=\frac{(k+x)!}{(2k+1)! . ((k+x)-(2k +1))!}$

$=\binom{k+x}{2k+1}$
$\square$

Comment: The first lines prove b) using a). What did you intend to achieve with the rest of the answer? It looks rather circular.